# Error while writing to a file after joining list of values

Tags: python

I am trying to write some values of a list after joining to a file and running into following error,any inputs on how to fix this?

```
data_changes ={'305403': ['302180'], '312994': ['311957'], '311957': ['312621'] }
modem_changes = {'305403': [], '313113': [], '312994': ['253036', '312591'], '311957': []}

dc_set = set(data_changes)
mc_set = set(modem_changes)

with open('file.txt', 'w+') as f:
    for key in dc_set.intersection(mc_set):
        union_values = data_changes[key] + modem_changes[key]
        values = key, ','.join(union_values)
        f.write(values)

with open('file.txt', 'a') as f:
    for key in dc_set.symmetric_difference(mc_set):
        dc_values = data_changes.get(key) or []
        mc_values = data_changes.get(key) or []
        union_values = dc_values + mc_values
        values=key, ','.join(union_values)
        f.write(values)
```

ERROR:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "final_build_list.py", line 31, in <module>
    f.write(values)
TypeError: argument 1 must be string or read-only character buffer, not tuple
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`values=key, ','.join(union_values)` is a `tuple` not `string` and you can't write a tuple to a file.

```
>>> foo = 1,2 # comma separated values on RHS are converted to tuple
>>> type(foo)
<type 'tuple'>
```

May be you were looking for:

```
values= "{0}, {1}\n".format(key, ','.join(union_values))
```

example:

```
data_changes ={'305403': ['302180'], '312994': ['311957'], '311957': ['312621'] }
modem_changes = {'305403': [], '313113': [], '312994': ['253036', '312591'], '311957': []}

dc_set = set(data_changes)
mc_set = set(modem_changes)

with open('abc', 'w+') as f:
    for key in dc_set.intersection(mc_set):
        union_values = data_changes[key] + modem_changes[key]
        values= "{0}, {1}\n".format(key, ','.join(union_values))
        f.write(values)
```

output (abc's content):

```
311957, 312621
305403, 302180
312994, 311957,253036,312591
```

Comment: what does {0} and {1} represent?,why only {0} ,{1},why not {2} too?

Comment: my end goal is to put "key, ','.join(union_values)" in a file

Comment: @user2341103 {0} the location where the first argument to format is going to be placed and {1} is position for the second argument. read more about string formatting : http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples

Comment: @Aswini Chaudhary - it wont work for me..there might be more than two values

Comment: Chaudary - it looks fine but when i write to the file..all of the values are printing in one line...i tried to append  "\n"   values= "{0} {1}\n".format(key, ' '.join(union_values)) but doesnt seem to be working

Comment: do you see the output getting printed in new lines in the file?

Comment: @user2341103 yes, I've added my output in my answer.